# where there is a space between the two div?

Tags: html, css

http://xanlz.com/template/

why there is a space between   `<div class="nav-top">...</div>`  and <`div class="nav-inner clear">   </div>`? (the test navigation and the bottom part)

how to alter it. thank you.

the correct style shows as this [image]. the two parts is joined together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because the links in your navigation has a fixed height of 23px. Change it to 21px.

Specifically, th erule I'm talking about is

```
.nav-top ul li.navahead a, .nav-top ul li.navmiddle a
```

in style.css

I used firebug to debug this in 2 minutes. You should use it too!

Comment: +1 - beat me by a minute. I agree, Firebug is the best tool out there for this kind of stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Change the height of your  tags from 23px to 21px.

```
.nav-top ul li.navahead a, .nav-top ul li.navmiddle a {
    color: #094884;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 21px;
    padding-top: 9px;
    width: 98px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`nav-innerclear` is not defined in your CSS. Put its `margin-top` to `0px`.